# Why is my imported VueJS Component not displayed?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following Vue view named "PasswordResetView":

```
<template>
  <v-content>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title primary-title>
        Passwort ändern
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-text>
        <v-text-field
                id="password"
                label="Passwort"
                name="password"
                prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
                type="password"
        />
        <v-text-field
                id="passwordRepeated"
                label="Passwort wiederholen"
                name="passwordRepeated"
                prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
                type="password"
        />
        <v-text-field
                id="mail"
                label="E-Mail"
                name="mail"
                prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
                type="text"
        />
      </v-card-text>

    </v-card>
  </v-content>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {

  name: "passwordreset",
  data() {
    return {
      password: "",
      passwordRepeated: "",
      mail: "",
      errormessage: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changePassword() {
      let payload = {mail: this.mail, password:this.password, passwordRepeated: this.passwordRepeated};
      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/anonymous/register/pwreset",
        data: payload,
      }).then(() => {
        this.$props.passwortresetkey = "good"
      })
    },

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped/>
```

The view is imported by another vue component "PasswordReset" as following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PasswordReset v-if="pwresetkey === 'good'"></PasswordReset>
    <div v-else>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          Passwort ändern
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Leider ist der Link ungültig.
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import PasswordReset from "../../../components/anon/PasswordReset";

export default {
    name:"passwordreset",
    components: PasswordReset
};
</script>
```

The corresponding router:

```
{
        path: "/pwreset",
        name: "pwreset",
        meta: {
            requiresDisponent: false,
            requiresRecurring: false,
            requiresOneTime: false,
            requiresAnon: true
        },
        component: () => import("@/views/recurring/account/PasswordReset"),
        props: true
    },
```

However, when I start the application, only the content from "PasswordReset" is shown (the v-card), but not the input fields.
Also, in the component "PasswordReset" it says that export default is ununsed.

Why is this marked as unused and the view not imported?

Comment: `components: PasswordReset` -> `components: {PasswordReset}`

Comment: `<password-reset>`?

Comment: Both components have the same `name` value. Have you tried changing one of them? I think you may be confusing the template compiler...

Comment: Changing the name did not solve the problem. I changed the view into "PasswordResetFormular" Now it says that the "PasswordResetFormular" component has been registered but is not used

Answer (score 2):

From vuejs [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing):

If you use kebab-case

```
Vue.component('my-component-name', { /* ... */ })
```

> When defining a component with kebab-case, you must also use kebab-case when referencing its custom element, such as in .

if you use PascalCase

```
Vue.component('MyComponentName', { /* ... */ })
```

> When defining a component with PascalCase, you can use either case when referencing its custom element. That means both  and  are acceptable. Note, however, that **only kebab-case names are valid directly in the DOM** (i.e. non-string templates).

Comment: And where should I put this line of code? In Component registration vuejs file or in the file that is not displayed?

Comment: what do you mean.. didn't understand what your question. @Panzerkroete

Comment: In which file should I write the line with `Vue.component(...)` ?

Comment: depends... did you use vue-cli to create a project?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your password reset component like so:

```
<script>
import PasswordReset from "../../../components/anon/PasswordReset";

export default {
    name:"passwordreset",
    components: {PasswordReset}
};
</script>
```

[VueJS Component Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)